# Python value distributor of a fixed total

Tags: python, function, loops

I would like to distribute a fixed number of hours (as an  input) among those rows from a dataframe that are best rated.
My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
id = np.array([1022, 1085, 1086, 1090, 1100, 1140, 1173, 1191])
avail = np.array([22, 16, 29, 18, 2, 8, 9, 13])
base = np.array(['bcn','bcn','bio','agp','bcn','bio','bcn','bcn'])
pd.to_numeric(avail)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([id, avail, base]), columns=['id', 'avail', 'base'] )
df
df.sort_values('avail', ascending=False)
df = df.astype({"avail": int, "avail": int})
sorteddf = df.sort_values('avail', ascending=False)
sorteddf = sorteddf.assign(hour_extra = 0)
sorteddf
row_num = sorteddf['id'].count()
sorteddf.index = range(0,row_num)
sorteddf
```

[image]

This is the sample dataset where avail represents priority.
Then, I would like to distribute a fixed value of "days" among them in a fair way. Example: It is in total 8 rows. Input of 13 would mean "1" for each and "2" for first 5.

My code I tried was the following:

```
limit = int(input())
total = sum(sorteddf['hour_extra'])
dataset = enumerate(sorteddf['hour_extra'])
for index, i in dataset:
sorteddf['hour_extra'][index] += 1
if index == limit-1:
break
print(sorteddf['hour_extra'])
```

But this just adds 1 value, meaning with input of 3 it gives 1 to first 3, great..but with an input of 13 it does not work.

Any idea how I can tackle it please? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I don't really understand the relationship between priority and number of given days. Can you elaborate on what you consider _fair sharing_ ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for commenting.
Keep it simple. It is just adding 1 in an iteration to the top given days.
For example 4 would mean: 
0 | 1086 | 29 | bio | 1
-
1 | 1022 | 22 | bcn | 1
-
2 | 1090 | 18 | agp | 1
-
3 | 1085 | 16 | bcn | 1
-
4 | 1191 | 13 | bcn | 0
-
5 | 1173 | 9 | bcn | 0
-
6 | 1140 | 8 | bio | 0
-
7 | 1100 | 2 | bcn | 0


but in case of 13:
-
0 | 1086 | 29 | bio | 2
-
1 | 1022 | 22 | bcn | 2
-
2 | 1090 | 18 | agp | 2
-
3 | 1085 | 16 | bcn | 2
-
4 | 1191 | 13 | bcn | 2
-
5 | 1173 | 9 | bcn | 1
-
6 | 1140 | 8 | bio | 1
-
7 | 1100 | 2 | bcn | 1

Comment: There is no relation between the value of days and the priority. Just a sort + add a number to the top x